# Why do I get a segmentation fault while iterating through this vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std

I need to go through this vector and delete the duplicates. A segmentation fault is occurring somewhere within this code. My guess is that it has something to do with deleting elements while the iterator is going through, but I don't really have a concrete understanding of how these iterators are actually working yet, so I can't figure it out.

```
vector<char *>::iterator iter;
for (iter = v->begin(); iter != v->end()-1; iter++ ){
    char *aString = *iter;
    int n = 1;
    while(iter+n != v->end()){
        int comparison = strcmp(aString, *(iter+n));
        if(comparison == 0){
            v->erase(iter + n);
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't guess. Run it in the debugger and find out what's causing the seg fault.

Comment: The vector is not empty by any chance, is it?

Comment: @weezybizzle - see my answer, you really only have a couple small off-by-one errors in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you just have a couple off-by-one problems here. You were comparing incorrectly against `end()` and incrementing `n` when you erased an element:

```
for (iter = v->begin(); iter != v->end()-1; iter++ ){
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

And

```
while(iter+n != v->end())
             ^^
```

The following will do what you want (and demonstrate that it works):

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<const char*> v (4, "this");
    std::vector<const char *>::iterator iter;

    for (iter = v.begin(); iter <  v.end(); iter++ ) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (iter = v.begin(); iter <  v.end(); iter++ ){
        const char *aString = *iter;
        int n = 1;
        while(iter+n < v.end()){
            int comparison = strcmp(aString, *(iter+n));
            if(comparison == 0){
                v.erase(iter + n);
            }
            else
                n++;
        }
    }

    for (iter = v.begin(); iter <  v.end(); iter++ ) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Output is:

> this this this this
>  
>   this

Comment: Thats worked out for me, thanks so much. So is the v.end() pointing to the last element in the vector? or is it sort of like a null terminator in a string, just an element that specifies the end?

Comment: @weezybizzle - `vector.end()` returns an iterator that refers to the *past-the-end* element in the vector container rather than the last element.

Comment: Your `iter != v.end()-1` would segfault when there was only 1 element left in the vector due to erasure and then the iterator was incremented to `v.end()`. You could write `iter <= v.end()-1` but it's kinda ugly; `iter < v.end()` is the normal way to write it.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Thanks so much @BrianRoach

Answer (score 2):

You are not properly iterating through the remainder of the vector.  An alternative to what Beta suggested is to use erase-remove with remove_if.  Like this:

```
bool compare_strings(char * aString,char * bString)
{
    return 0==strcmp(aString,bString);
}

void remove_duplicates(vector<char *> * v)
{
    vector<char *>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = v->begin(); iter != v->end(); iter++ ) {
        v->erase(std::remove_if(iter+1,v->end(),compare_strings),v->end());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you erase an element from the vector, the vector gets one element shorter. Try this:

```
if(comparison == 0){
  v->erase(iter + n);
}
else{
  n++;
}
```

Comment: still getting the segmentation fault with that

Answer (score 1):

Erasing from a vector invalidates all iterators from the erasee onwards, so you should probably not construct your loop the way you do, and rather use a standard idiom like this:

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)   // no end() - 1 -- may not be legal!
{
  for (auto jt = it; jt != v.end(); )
  {
    if (jt == it) continue;

    if (strcmp(*it, *jt) == 0)
    {
      jt = v.erase(jt);
    }
    else
    {
      ++jt;
    }
  }
}
```

This code avoids the check for an empty vector, which your code fails to account for.

Comment: He's not erasing the element referred to by the iterator so it isn't invalidated (or am I missing something?).

Comment: You need to initialze n to 1, otherwise it will compare the string against itself.

Comment: @IronMensan: Fixed! Note that I insist on starting at zero so that we don't need extra non-emptiness checks.

Comment: @KerrekSB - please check your answer; he's not invalidating his iterator. He just has a couple off-by-one problems.

Comment: @BrianRoach: The two problems with the OP's code are that there's no check that the vector is non-empty, and that `strcmp` is used which expects null-termination. You're right that `iter++` is actually still OK, since `n > 0`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Cool. I agree with your other assessments but at the same time, his original code wasn't horribly flawed.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about using `strncmp`.  Why would the `char *`s inside the vector be pointing to the vector itself?  What does `std::distance(it + n, v.end())` have to do with the memory the `char *`s are pointing at?

Comment: @IronMensan: If the strings are in fact identical, then `strcmp` would just go on comparing until it hits the terminating null. But since you don't have one, you run right off the end of the vector into undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BrianRoach: You're right. That was a bit too much of a knee-jerk reaction of me that I get whenever someone uses `erase` on a vector in a loop that includes `iter++`. In this case that was OK.

Comment: @Kerrek It's `vector<char *>` not `vector<char>`.  `strcmp` should only be used with null-terminated strings, but there is nothing in a `vector<char *>` that gives any indiction about the length of the strings pointed at by the `char *`s in the vector.

Comment: @IronMensan: Ohh, my bad - I just got that wrong. Let me delete the offending part. Sorry!

Comment: I rewrote the algorithm and I like it much better now. It's more symmetric and more efficient than my original one.